# Parent know if inner child handles click

Tags: android, android-layout

My parent view needs to know if one of its inner views as handled or not a click event. The items that handle click events are inside a horizontal `recyclerview` (Only one item at a time is visible in the screen).

This is the layout that I have

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentViewThatNeedToknowIfClickHasHappened"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    .... More views

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/viewThatHasItemsThatReceiveClicks
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                ....More Views
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

.... more views

</FrameLayout>
```

The `recyclerview` item has many views and some of them have click listeners attached. When clicking one of those items, a popup view becomes visible. When the popup is visible and I touch one of the other views that handle clicks, the popup content is updated.

What I need to achieve in my parent view (`parentViewThatNeedToknowIfClickHasHappened`) is this:

- Do nothing if the popup view isn't showing;
- If the popup view is showing:

  - Dismiss the popup if none of the items in `viewThatHasItemsThatReceiveClicks` that can receive clicks, will be clicked.
  - Do nothing if any of the items in `viewThatHasItemsThatReceiveClicks` that can receive clicks, will be clicked.

In my `parentViewThatNeedToknowIfClickHasHappened` I've overridden `onInterceptTouchEvent` but I wasn't able to get to any conclusion, that is knowing what will happen in the items of the `recyclerview`.

Any idea how can I achieve what I pretend?

Comment: you can get child views count of any parent view.

Comment: But how can I know it it will handle the click or not?